# How to get all elements to the right of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position

I have several absolute positioned elements. Is it possible to get all elements with a position that's to the right of the current element?

If yes, how to do this?

Comment: You should be able to do this via `.position()`: http://api.jquery.com/position/ and `.offset()`: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just written a plugin which implements this feature. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FJ5Cp/1/**

The function logic should bbe similar to:

1. Get the current element's left position and offset width. Add these together to get the right border.
2. Get the left position and offset width of each element, add these to get the right border. Compare this value to the value at one.

Usage and function:

```
// Basic usage
var allRightElements = $("element").rightOfCurrent();
// Only select ___ elements which are located right of the current element
var allRightElementsFilter = $("element").rightOfCurrent("___");
// Only select ___ elements, which are located right of the current element,
//   which are childs of ####
var allRightFilterInsideSomething = $("element").rightOfCurrent("___", "###");

(function($){
    $.fn.rightOfCurrent = function(selector, context){
        elem = this.eq(0);
        selector = selector || '*';
        context = context || null;
        var currentRight = elem.offset().left + elem.width();
        return $(selector, context).filter(function(){
           var $this = $(this);
           if ($this.css('position') == 'absolute'){
               return $this.offset().left + $this.width() > currentRight;
           }
           return false;
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 I had nearly finished writing an almost identical plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter()`, comparing each element's `.offset().left` with that of the current element:

```
var l = currentElement.offset().left;
var righterElements = positionedElements.filter(function(){
    return $(this).offset().left > l;
});
```